# Coloured output in Turbo C++

Tags: c++, colors, dos, turbo-c++, dosbox

My compiler is [Turbo C++ v3.0 with DOS v5.0 emulated in DOSBox v0.74](http://turboc-for-windows.soft32.com/)
I use this because Turbo C++ is the compiler with which
my highschool has chosen to teach the C++ programming language.
It has been stressed that I use this compiler while coding my final term project.

I'm running Windows 8.1 (64 bit) with Intel Core i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz

For the sake of liveliness and in tribute to popular culture,
**I want my output screens to have green text.**

The following is what seemed to work :

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(){
 clrscr();
 textcolor(2); // text set to green colour (conio.h function)
 cprintf("\n\t Hello World"); // cprintf from conio.h
 cout << "\n\t Hello World"; // cout from iostream.h
 getch();
}
```

The output of which is as follows <sup><sub>(screen has been trimmed to save space on this post)</sub></sup>:

[image: hello world]

According to the Help Section in Turbo C++,

> `cprintf()` sends formatted output to the text window on the screen.

As you can see, the text printed onto the screen by `cout` is not green and my project is composed of a lot of `cin` and `cout` and some writing and reading files.

The result I desire can (although I have not yet tried) most likely be obtained by replacing all my `cout << "...";` with `cprintf("...");`
but I've written so many cout statements that it's going to be hard to edit the code that much.

`cprintf` is new territory for me and I'm slightly set aback by how
`cprintf("\t");` is outputed as `o`

So, I'm not to keen using this. I don't wish to use this until and unless it is my only option.

The libraries `cstdlib.h` and `windows.h` are unavailable in Turbo C++ and hence I can't use their utilities to get what I want either.

In the end, all I want is that output prompt to display the text I've `cout`ed in bright green. Minimal change to my code would be nice.
I wouldn't even mind having to change some settings of my emulator or compiler or shell to do it.

All help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance =)

Comment: FYI, the course is most likely doing you more harm than good.

Comment: @chris: I know, and I promise to relearn C++ the moment I'm through with school. But for now, I'm stuck using a compiler older than I am and writing code that even the cryptkeeper thinks is outdated.

Comment: I've not used Turbo C++ in decades but, I remember when it was widely regarded as 'The Best'.  I wonder if there is a facility in their iostreams implementation that allows one to do something like cout.color(0x0020ff). Something like we do to set the fill characters: cout.fill('#'); or field width: cout.width(4);

Comment: another thought, can you set the foreground color in DOSBox?

Comment: @BradS. I have searched a lot and I have no leads on such a method of cout. Also, I'm unable to edit any settings of the dosbox instance because I've downloaded the turboc++ and dosbox as a package. I've added a link to it in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the 1990s called, they want their QEMM back :)

The one solution I can think of is to put this in your CONFIG.SYS:

```
DEVICE=C:\DOS\ANSI.SYS
```

and then output [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: Actually, I can think of another solution: some sort of curses library, e.g. there used to be a PCCurses library around 1992:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.msdos/t3oX7908rsc

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constream library for colored text output:

```
#include <constrea.h>
int main()
{
    constream cout;
    cout << setclr(2);
    cout << "\n\t Hello, World!" << endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what to do about the tab character.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add the clrscr(); function after the textcolor(); and it works with the couts